# How to scrape data from an almost empty html in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-scraping

So basically website's html looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>123445.87</body>
</html>
```

I need to scrape those numbers that are in the body, that's all there is to that html. How do I do that? Because when I debug this program it just says "Error: no data scraped". Here's my code:

```
[ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        [Route("scrape")]
        [AcceptVerbs("GET")]

        public async Task<List<string>> GetValue()
        {
            List<string> Datalst = new List<string>();
            HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage result = await hc.GetAsync($"https://mywebsite.com/");
            Stream stream = await result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.Load(stream);
            var Value = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//html/body");

            if (Value == null)
                Datalst.Add("Error: no data scraped");

            else
            {
                foreach (var item in Value)
                {
                    Datalst.Add(item.InnerText);
                }
            }

            return Datalst;
        }
    }
```

Comment: So, what is the issue?

Comment: I cannot scrape the value which is in <body></body> using this code, and I can't find any solution

Comment: what is the outcome?

Comment: "Error: no data scraped" and in the error list it just shows that it is "Value: Null reference exception"

Comment: The code seems fine. Probably the website cannot be loaded or something. Try to debug it and check what is in the "doc" after load or what is in the stream.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution!
Basically I changed this line of code:

```
var Value = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//html/body");
```

To this:

```
var Value = doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
```